# Server side request rejection using Spring Web's CorsWebFilter

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

When perusing the implementation of Spring Web (5.2.9)'s `CorsWebFilter` & `DefaultCorsProcessor` I noticed that requests sent from a browser containing an origin that is not included inside the configuration's `allowedOrigins` are rejected in the filter and not passed on to the rest of the filter chain.

Everything I've read about CORS always says that:

1. CORS is there to relax the SOP, acting on the browser only.
2. CORS is not a valid way to prevent CSRF.

Is this rejection of request on the server-side that Spring does a deviation from the specs? If it is, how safe is it to rely on this implementation staying in upcoming versions of Spring?

Would you consider it a valid way to prevent CSRF? If I only allow a specific origin, requests made from other origins will always be rejected inside of the `CorsFilter`.

Comment: Why is it a deviation from the spec? What is implemented is the W3C recommendation for checks and pre-flight checks (see https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#cors-check).

Comment: I might have misinterperted that. But I do find many other answers here that claim that CORS will only block an attacker's browser from reading the response and does not block the server from performing the request. A few examples [1](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/154350/same-origin-policy-and-csrf-tokens/154356#154356) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29350797/how-does-csrf-protection-give-me-greater-security-than-cors-control-with-front-e/29409179#29409179) [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19793695/does-a-proper-cors-setup-prevent-xsrf/19793919#19793919)

Comment: Are they all wrong or is there something else that I do not understand?